# Why does getfacl remove the leading / from absolute pathnames?

Tags: linux, filenames, acl

I'm in the midst of learning about ACL's for CentOS/Red Hat 6; when I run `getfacl` using an absolute path, I get among the output:

> getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names

Why does it need to do this? In what situations would you need to use the `-p` or `--absolute-names` switch?

My books by Wale Soyinka and Michael Jang don't make even a passing mention of this, I'm not seeing any clues in the man page, and I can't seem to find any sites that directly address this warning.

Comment: It's been like this since [the dawn of ACL in Linux](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/acl.git/commit/facl/getfacl.c?id=f1479ac3d3bf18193bf24d6e1a09bd9726ac72d4). I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks for helping me look into it and for the link. My programming skills are a little rudimentary at the moment, but i've saved the file for when I start tackling C/C++ with my Gaddis book.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From man page of `getfacl`:

```
-p, --absolute-names
       Do not strip leading slash characters (`/'). The  default  behavior
       is to strip leading slash characters.
```

A warning message is emitted when you supply absolute path without using `-p` switch.

**Outputs are different when absolute path is given to the `getfacl` command.**

Without `-p` switch:

```
$ getfacl /path/foo/bar
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: path/foo/bar
[Output truncated...]
```

Note the leading slash in file path shows only when `-p` switch is used.

```
$ getfacl -p /path/foo/bar
# file: /path/foo/bar
[Output truncated...]
```

`-p` is useful to keep the leading slash when you piped the output for further processing.

**Outputs are the same when relative path is given to the `getfacl` command.**

```
$ getfacl bar
# file: bar
[Output truncated...]
```

No changes:

```
$ getfacl -p bar
# file: bar
[Output truncated...]
```

Comment: Forgive me, as i'm relatively new to Linux, but this seems like a pretty superfluous switch, since if you were piping the output to another program, you would have to edit the stream anyway to grab that section of the output in the first place, am I correct?  What would be an example case where it would be useful to strip the leading slash? Since it is an absolute path, it seems slightly silly to strip it in the first place.

Comment: In other distros (e.g. FreeBSD), this switch does not exist. By viewing the source of RHEL acl package, it seems that `--absolute-names` only deal with the output string – "# file:", but not the logic behind. At first I guess it may be a security feature. Nevertheless, the switch does not exist in `setfacl`. My last assumption is the author would like to simulate the `tar` behaviour though the `-p` switch usage on `getfacl` may be useless.

Comment: This doesn't answer the why though.  Why are leading slashes stripped by default, how does that ever help??

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that "*because you didn't use the '-p' flag*" really explains the **purpose** of this warning.

These commands are intended to implement fine-grained security measures, obviously with stronger security in mind that the traditional POSIX permissions allow for.

So I would look instead to security theory: consider what could go wrong in each case, and opt for the one default that is "safest".

1. Relative or absolute path used as intended: no problem.
2. Relative path used when absolute path should have been used: won't work, but unlikely to cause a security breach. (Also, can be fixed simply by `cd /` beforehand.)
3. Absolute path used when a relative path should have been used. This is what this restriction is designed to highlight.

Consider a project installation script that goes

```
setfacl -m u:1234:rw $project_dir/etc/passwd
```

Now think about what happens if there's a bug, and `$project_dir` is empty. (Maybe it should have been spelled `$projectdir`, or maybe the config file was missing and so it never got set, or there's some other kind of bug.)

And the same rationale applies to `getfacl`, because one of its use cases is this:

```
getfacl some/file | { make some changes } | setfacl -b -M- some/file
```

or equivalently

```
getfacl some/file > aclfile
edit aclfile
setfacl -b -M aclfile some/file
```

and perhaps more importantly

```
getfacl some/file > aclfile
edit aclfile
setfacl --restore=aclfile
```

(Note in the last case that the target filename is *not* included on the `setfacl` command line; it's read from the aclfile.)

You might think "it should work the same way as `chmod`, `chown`, `chgrp`, and `install`", and in a sense you'd be right: those commands would be safer if they had the same restriction on un-notified absolute paths.

But those commands have long historical precedent (and the POSIX standard behind them, mostly), so they're not really up for negotiation, even if security experts think that this would be a good idea.

This isn't without precedent elsewhere.

`rsync -R` treats the paths as relative on the receiving end, ignoring the leading `/`.

Archivers such as `cpio` and `tar` (which used to be used for package delivery before `deb` and `rpm` became popular) have options to trim the leading `/`, for the same reason, but with the opposite default setting (off).

Comment: It makes no sense to me that the uncritical `getfacl` complains about absolute paths while the much more sensitive `setfacl` accepts them without any special switches. If anything it should be the other way around.

Comment: In the simple setting I'd agree, but... consider the case where `getfacl` is being run by someone who supposedly knows what they're doing (such as someone creating a package), while a subsequent naïve user is told to run `setfacl --restore=aclfile` as part of the installation script. In that case I would prefer that the "experienced" person doesn't inadvertently create an ACL file with a timebomb in it.